# how to use standard time?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website where I need to show nigeria standard time. I am following this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx

Which time zone should i use ? and how can I make sure that always nigerian standard time is showin ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config you should set the globalization. For example:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
</system.web>
```

this is for germany. you need to set for nigeria.
I couldn't find for nigeria, may be africa: 'af':

```
culture="af" uiCulture="af"
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with time zones.

Comment: Is this not set automatically through the globalization?

Comment: No; it isn't.  For one thing, a single culture can have multiple timezones.

Comment: You should probably delete your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nigeria uses [West Africa Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Africa_Time).

You can therefore write

```
var nigeria = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Central Africa Standard Time");
var nigerianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, nigeria);
```